# How do I access an object in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json structured like this:

```
{
    "total": 4367,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "paging": {
        "next": "/videos?query=second%20world%20war&per_page=10&access_token=XXX&page=2",
        "previous": null,
        "first": "/videos?query=second%20world%20war&per_page=10&access_token=XXX&page=1",
        "last": "/videos?query=second%20world%20war&per_page=10&access_token=XXX&page=437"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "uri": "/videos/128373915",
            "name": "The Fallen of World War II",
```

I need to access `name` and I tried:

```
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: vimeoResultsFunc
        });
        function vimeoResultsFunc(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].name);
            }
        }
```

But i get nothing

Comment: why not just `var response = JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: @Conceptz: `data` is already parsed, thanks to jQuery knowing what `dataType: 'json'` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a level there. The vimeoResultsFunc will receive the top level object, then you have an array called data. Based on what you have it should be

```
function vimeoResultsFunc(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.data[i].name);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `vimeoResultsFunc(data)` just add `console.log(data)` and see what is inside the data object. Probably this object does not have the structure  you expect.